# Defining Proper TypeScript Interfaces

Tags: reactjs, typescript, lodash

I am new to Typescript and have run into an issue. I am building a React web app and also using lodash.

I am obtaining JSON data from an api.  for now, let's assume it has two keys:

```
{ 
  foo1 : 'something',
  bar1 : [{.. key:value data ..}, { .. key:value data ..}, ...]
}
```

how do I define an interface for this? primarily, the fact that I have an array of objects?  I've tried something like this:

```
interface MyThing {
  foo : string;
  bar : object[];
}
```

Then, in the reducer code, I have something like:

```
let things : MyThing[] = _.forEach(apiData.things, (thingData) => ({
        foo : thingData.stringItem,
        bar : thingData.arrayOfObjects
    }))
```

I wind up getting an error like this:

```
error TS2322: Type 'object' is not assignable to type 'MyThing[]'.
  Property 'find' is missing in type '{}'.
```

**Edit:**
after the suggestion, I made a mistake and meant to use _.map, not _.forEach.  this is the error I get.

```
ERROR in ./source/reducers/gamesReducer.ts
(37,40): error TS2345: Argument of type 'object' is not assignable to parameter of type 'List<{}> | Dictionary<{}> | NumericDictionary<{}>'.
  Type 'object' is not assignable to type 'NumericDictionary<{}>'.
    Index signature is missing in type '{}'.
```

Comment: Instead of `bar: object[]`, try `bar: {[key: string]: any}[]` or even just `bar: any[]`. Also I think you meant to use `_.map` instead of `_.forEach`.

Comment: oops. yes. meant to use _.map.

Comment: try capital O Object

Comment: I should add, that the api data, for bar1... each object item has more than one key:value pair. I changed the code to use _.map as I should.. and now I get a different error. I'll update the code. but it's this:`ERROR in ./source/reducers/gamesReducer.ts
(37,40): error TS2345: Argument of type 'object' is not assignable to parameter of type 'List<{}> | Dictionary<{}> | NumericDictionary<{}>'.
  Type 'object' is not assignable to type 'NumericDictionary<{}>'.
    Index signature is missing in type '{}'.`

Comment: Can you post an example of what the value of `apiData` could look like? Also which line is the compile error happening on?